# Group By Month With Overlapping years

Tags: postgresql

I want my query to show all months grouped together, regardless of the year.  For example, I would want this to be the output:

```
01/13/2015
01/01/2016
02/07/2015
02/01/2016
```

This is sample DDL - what must I alter so months are all displayed together regardless of year?

```
CREATE TABLE randomdate(dateofwork timestamp);

INSERT INTO randomdate VALUES('2016-01-01 00:00:00-05');
INSERT INTO randomdate VALUES('2015-01-13 00:00:00-05');
INSERT INTO randomdate VALUES('2016-02-01 00:00:00-05');
INSERT INTO randomdate VALUES('2015-02-07 00:00:00-05');


Select 
date_trunc('month',randomdate)
from randomdate
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', randomdate)
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', randomdate) ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_trunc` truncates the date to the specified part. You need `extract`

```
select extract('month' from dateofwork) from randomdate group by 1 order by 1;

+-------------+
|   date_part |
|-------------|
|           1 |
|           2 |
+-------------+
SELECT 2
Time: 0.005s
```

Comment: Is it possible to return the full date as well?  This returns only a numeric value for the month.

Comment: @user2676140 - the short answer is no, you can't do this - by performing the aggregation of `GROUP BY`, you "lost" information. As a comparison, consider an average - that provides summary information but the "price" you pay is losing your individual data points.

Comment: His example desired output indicates he doesn't actually want the `group by` anyway.  All he has to do is remove it (and keep just the `order by`).  Then he could just add `dateofwork` into the select list.

Comment: The goal of group by extract is to 'combine' different values by decreasing granularity and doing some aggregation. So having the 'full date' in the group by column is breaking the functionality as others pointed out before me. If you still need the original date you can use something like `array_agg` to return the list of (full) dates together with the other columns you're interested in: `select extract('month' from dateofwork), array_agg(dateofwork) from randomdate group by 1 order by 1;`

Answer (score 1):

this query will also have valid result:

```
Select date_part('month',dateofwork)
from randomdate
GROUP BY date_part('month', dateofwork)
ORDER BY date_part('month', dateofwork) ASC
```

Comment: Is it possible, to still return the full date as well?

Comment: you cannot do it with group by expression. maybe with windowing functions but i need to check it first.